# Loading a stream of images in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Here is my code for the callback function.

```
function Next_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

display('Click Next');
handles.imgLNum = strcat('I1_',num2str(handles.imageNumber),'.png');
handles.imgRNum = strcat('I2_',num2str(handles.imageNumber),'.png');

handles.imageLeft = strcat(handles.directory,handles.imgLNum);
handles.imageRight = strcat(handles.directory,handles.imgRNum);

axes(handles.img1);
imshow(handles.imageLeft);
axes(handles.img2);
imshow(handles.imageRight);
handles.imageNumber = handles.imageNumber+1;
```

I have a button called "Next" on my GUI and I want to load the next image into the axes when it is clicked. `handles.imageLeft` and `handles.imageRight` have the path for the images. When the hit the button the first time, the axes gets updated with the images. But subsequent clicks on the button do not update the axes. But the 'Click Next' text is displayed in console, so I know the callback function is being called.

Comment: You need first to read the image by, for example, `Img=imread(handles.imageRight)`, and then you can call `imshow(Img)`. `imshow` will not work on a path, only on a matrix.

Comment: I tried that too. But even that gets me stuck at the same spot.

Comment: Please edit and show what exactly have you tried

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/aakaashjois/7323826251b89f9a69271a8d15d7f6e8) is the complete code which I have done till now

Comment: Ok, I don't see issue there, but I'm not going debugging it for you, sorry... Set some breakpoints and go each line, check where is the problem...

Comment: Cool. Thank you for trying :D

Comment: Oh, you probably should change directly the handles, not via `imshow`. Try something like `set(handles.image1..., imgL)`

Comment: Another option is use `imshow` with `handles.img1` in the  `parent` property.

Comment: It gives an error saying "Invalid handle" when I try to set it.

Comment: @Adiel Thank you so much for the help. I changed the handles directly as you suggested and then set the data using imshow and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Adiel for the help. I find the problem following your suggestions. I updated the `handles.imageLeft` and `handles.imageRight` and I added the code `guidata(hObject, handles);` I think this function updates the handles (This is my first MATLAB GUI, so I am not very sure). Now the problem is fixed.